# Right way to construct a binary tree?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

Suppose we have a class `BinaryTree` defined as follows (which cannot be modified):

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value
        if self.value is not None:
            self.left_node = BinaryTree()
            self.right_node = BinaryTree()
        else:
            self.left_node = None
            self.right_node = None
```

And I have a stack, which consists of numbers and '+'s, e.g,

```
stack = ['1', '2', '+', '3', '4', '5', '+', '+', '+']
```

Now I want to a construct the binary tree. The rule is as follows:
starting from right to left, the root is '+'.
Then if the character is '+', extend the branch,
else, we add numbers from `left_node` to `right_node`.

By the order I pop the last element in my list, the detailed illustration of the process is as follows:

```
t = BinaryTree('+')
t.left_node = BinaryTree('+')
t.left_node.left_node = BinaryTree('+')
t.left_node.left_node.left_node = BinaryTree('5')
t.left_node.left_node.right_node = BinaryTree('4')
t.left_node.right_node = BinaryTree('3')
t.right_node = BinaryTree('+')
t.right_node.left_node = BinaryTree('2')
t.right_node.right_node = BinaryTree('1')
```

So eventually the visual representation of the tree is something like this[image: visual representation of the tree]

I know I need to approach this problem using recursion and control structure, but I am not sure how this can be applied to adding nodes in the tree.

If anything needs to be clarified please let me know and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a standard introductory data structures question. If it is homework, you might find [this Meta Stack Overflow topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) useful for asking this question.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thank you for your reminder. Yes, it is indeed part of the homework that I am stuck with at the moment.

Comment: Since it's homework, which of the Algorithms texts are you using (or have on hand from a previous class)? Cormen? Sedgewick?

Comment: Oh we don't have a textbook, the lecturer explained the binary tree but this challenge requires rather knowledge on recursion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

- define a function that builds a node using a list and returns what's left of the list:

  def noding(l):

  ```
  t = BinaryTree(l[-1])
  if l[-1] == '+':
      left, rest = noding(l[:-1])
      t.left_node = left
      right, rest = noding(rest)
      t.right_node = right
      return t, rest
  if l[-1] != '+':
      return t, l[-1]
  ```

It's a bit raw, I don't have time to really think it thoroughly, especially with the handling of None.

Edit : don't return None, but return l[:-1] like previously.

Comment: Thank you Marc for your tip, it really helped me as I was stuck with the idea that I have to call the recursive function after my return statement. Your answer was great, however, just for the purpose of this question, I would slightly change l[-1] into l.pop() as I am progressing the list. This really helped me thank you very much!